# Resource cannot be found (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I moved a solution from one machine to another and am having nightmares.  I've got one problem left.  The default page can't get served, it says Resource cannot be found.  I have in the routeConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I get Resource cannot be found.

I can access the default page by :-

http://example.com/home/index

The other questions don't seem to answer it.

EDIT: If I put the above line of code at the top of the Routing code, the default page works but other pages don't.  If I put the code at the bottom, other pages work but the default page doesn't.

Comment: it can be IIS configuration

Comment: The problem is on both the dev machine and on the shared hosting server.  The problem occured when I swapped dev machines but the routeconfig.cs was copied exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had two Config Rules pointing to the same address.  One of the other rules was pointing to the wrong controller.  The wrong controller was erroring because I had set up the action, I had used the name of the controller as the action, thats a no-no.  The above rule was correct but the incorrect rule was

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "pagelist",
            url: "pagelist",
            defaults: new { controller = "pagelist", action = "pagelist", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

the action should have been Index.

Answer (score 0):

Try look in properties there is "Web" tab were you cat chose server and project URL, hope

Comment: Can you expand on what I need to look for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only default routing on RouteConfig file in development machine and keep getting 404, it seems that your problem comes from project's virtual path settings.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1893154.aspx?The+resource+cannot+be+found+404

> If application is deployed on local host (or you have set Use local IIS
>   Web Server) then it means you have created a virtual directory named
>   "YourSite".

Right click your app project on VS, choose Properties, then go to "Web" part and set your site's virtual path on "Project Url".

For virtual directory problem on live IIS server, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804(v=ws.10).aspx) to add virtual directory into destination machine before deploying your app.

In addition, if you have custom routing rule, make sure the custom route placed properly on top of default routing rule.